# Draw a line that pass the A point and crossing point with geometrical solution

Tags: geometry

Two lines $D$ and $L$ are in a plane (lines are not parallel) and we don't know their crossing point. We also have a point $A$ around those two lines.

How can we draw a line that passes by A and the intersection of that two lines? (I need the basics steps).

Comment: Find the intersection of the two lines and call that $P$. You now have $P$ and $A$ so you can find the line.

Comment: Extend the two lines with your ruler to get the intersection point. Then connect that point with $A$ and you are done.

Comment: What exactly do you want? I don't see what "we can't find that point" means. Do you mean we are not allowed to consider anything about the intersection point? or do you simply imply that you can't find it because you can't extend the lines to find it since the paper is too small? Are you trying to actually drawing one with a particular set of lines given to you, or are you speaking in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Thales Theorems.if we assume A point is upper than line D and line D is upper than L line ,do this :1-draw a line from A to those lines and call it ABC.2- draw a parallel line between two lines(with some space between them) so that the line start at line L and call it MN.then use Thales Theorems: BC/MN = AB/NP . NP is the continue of the MN. now we have 2 points A and P.connect this two points together and it will be our line.

Comment: thank you for your answer.